# Some headers of pandas dataframe are shown as attributes but no all in Debug > Variables in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a dataframe `df` that has a lot of columns (809) and one row. I've created it like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([prepared_line], columns=headers)
```

where `prepared_line` and `headers` are `list`. Values in `headers` are a mix between *CamelCase* and *snake_case* thus there is no space.

When I look for `df` in the DEBUG tab of vscode, I can see that some of the columns headers are shown like this (note the App* attributes) as `Series`:

[image]

But not all of them (probably because there is 809 of them) and what I find strange is that, even though this is in alphabetic order, some headers are not displayed.

Is this normal for a pandas dataframe to be displayed like this in vscode or is there something I'm missing?

Headers that are displayed are `Series`, from what vcsode tell. Does vscode debug only display `Series` and if so why my columns are not all `Series` ?

Thanks in advance for any help,

I hope this is the correct place to ask.

Comment: If you can provide more details about exactly what you think is missing and a way to reproduce the problem you can open an issue at github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.